# Log user activity in ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, architecture

I am planning to create filter based on `ActionFilterAttribute` to log user activity:

```
public class LogAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public ActionType Type { get; set; }

    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
      // logic for log
    }
}
```

I would like to use this attribute on Actions in my controllers. I'd like to log some values `X,Y,Z` which user is set in my views and also some action related info. In that case I have to probably send these X,Y,Z to my actions as parameters and then in Attribute code get these values from ResultExecutedContext. But this approach confused a little bit me because I will have redundant parameters on each of my actions.

Is there any good approach to share values from View to C# code?

Answer (score 3):

I am able to achieve this by following the below way

Create a table(name - `Portal_Logger` and `D_MASTER` )

Next, Created a filter which will track the activity for user/s like below

**LoggerActionFilter.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Net;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using MyMvcApplication.Models.Entity;
using MyMvcApplication.Utilities;

namespace MyMvcApplication.Filters
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public class LoggerActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        private static TimeZoneInfo INDIAN_ZONE = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time");
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            // Stores the Request in an Accessible object
            var request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
            var visitCount = Convert.ToInt64(filterContext.HttpContext.Session["LoggerActivityTracking"].ToString());
            // Generate an audit
            Portal_Logger aLogger = new Portal_Logger()
            {
                // Your Logger Identifier     
                LoggerId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                //Logged On User Id
                LogedUserId = Convert.ToInt32(filterContext.HttpContext.Session["LogedUserID"]),
                // The IP Address of the Request
                IPAddress = Convert.ToString(ipHostInfo.AddressList.FirstOrDefault(address => address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)),
                //Get the Web Page name(from the URL that was accessed)
                AreaAccessed = UserActivityUtility.GetWebPageName(request.RawUrl == "/"? "/Home/UserLandingPage" : request.RawUrl),
                // Creates our Timestamp
                Timestamp = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, INDIAN_ZONE),
                VisitorSessionId = visitCount
            };
            
            // Stores the Logger in the Database
            using (dbEntities context = new dbEntities())
            {
                if (aLogger.LogedUserId != null)
                {
                    aLogger.LogedUserEmpId = context.D_MASTER
                        .Where(x => x.User_Id == aLogger.LogedUserId)
                        .Select(x => x.Emp_Id).FirstOrDefault();
                    aLogger.LogedUserEmpName = context.D_MASTER
                        .Where(x => x.User_Id == aLogger.LogedUserId)
                        .Select(x => x.Emp_Name).FirstOrDefault();
                    aLogger.AccessedType = aLogger.AreaAccessed.Contains("Report") ? "Report" : "Page";
                }
                context.Portal_Logger.Add(aLogger);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            // Finishes executing the Logger as normal 
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }

    }
}
```

Note : `Session["LoggerActivityTracking"]` and `Session["LogedUserID"]` data i am initializing in a Separate Controller(`AuthController`) Action(`ValidateUser`) which executes when user logging into the application.

Below i am using a Utility class which will get the exact name for the web page from the RawUrl(eg : `/Home/MyController` or `/Home/MyController1?id=1&name=chandan`)

Below is my Utility Class

**UserActivityUtility.cs**

```
using System;       
namespace MyMvcApplication.Utilities
{
    public static class UserActivityUtility
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="pageName"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string GetWebPageName(string pageName)
        {
            string formattedPageName = string.Empty;
            //For All user web pages
            if (pageName.Contains("UserLandingPage"))
            {
                formattedPageName = "Home - App Management";
            }            
            //For Report Web Pages 
            else if (pageName.Contains("AppUtilization"))
            {
                formattedPageName = "Application Utilization Report";
            }           
            else if (pageName.Contains("AlertReport"))
            {
                formattedPageName = "Alert Report";
            }                       
            else
            {
                formattedPageName = pageName;
            }
            return formattedPageName;
        }
    }
}
```

And finally apply that attribute to the Controller Action/s(which actions you want to track) like below

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [LoggerActionFilter(Order = 1)]
    public ActionResult UserLandingPage()
    {
        return View();
    }
}


public class AdminController : Controller
{
    [LoggerActionFilter(Order = 1)]
    public ActionResult CreateUser()
    {
        return View();
    }
}


public class ReportController : Controller
{
    [LoggerActionFilter(Order = 1)]
    public ActionResult AppUtilization()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

And below are the "MS SQL StoredProcedure" to get the user login details and page wise access summary details

**User Login Details**

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE Procedure [dbo].[sp_Portal_GetUserLoginDetails_Logger]
(
@FromDate DATE,
@ToDate DATE
)
AS
BEGIN
        --EXEC sp_Portal_GetUserLoginDetails_Logger '2017-06-16','2017-06-16'
        SET NOCOUNT ON

        SELECT  u.LogedUserID,u.UserName,u.IPAddress,u.AreaAccessed,u.[Timestamp],u.LastLoggedInDay
        FROM 
        (
                SELECT  DISTINCT l.LogedUserID,e.Emp_Name as 'UserName',l.IPAddress,l.AreaAccessed,l.[Timestamp],l.LastLoggedInDay
                FROM 
                (
                        SELECT * 
                        FROM 
                        (
                            SELECT  Row_Number() Over ( PARTITION BY LogedUserID ORDER BY [Timestamp] DESC) As RowNum, LogedUserID,

                                    IPAddress,AreaAccessed,TIMESTAMP, DATEDIFF(D,TIMESTAMP,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS 'LastLoggedInDay'
                            FROM    Portal_Logger 
                            WHERE   CAST([Timestamp] AS DATE) BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
                        ) t2
                    WHERE RowNum = 1
                ) l
                JOIN D_MASTER e on l.LogedUserID = e.User_Id                
        ) u     
        ORDER BY u.[Timestamp] DESC     
END
```

**Page Wise Access Summary Details**

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Portal_GetUserAccessedSummary_Logger]
(
@FromDate DATE,
@ToDate DATE
)
AS
BEGIN       
        --EXEC sp_Portal_GetUserAccessedSummary_Logger '2017-06-16','2017-06-16'

        SET NOCOUNT ON      
            SELECT  A.AreaAccessed,
                    COUNT(A.Timestamp) AS NoofTimeAccessed,
                    CONVERT(TIME(0), DATEADD(SECOND,SUM(SessionSeconds), 0)) AS TotalTimeSpent,
                    CONVERT(TIME(0), DATEADD(SECOND,AVG(SessionSeconds), 0)) AS AvgTimeSpent,
                    COUNT(DISTINCT LogedUserID) AS NoofUserAccessed
  
            FROM
            (
                SELECT  
                        A.AreaAccessed,A.Timestamp,
                        ISNULL(DATEDIFF(S,A.Timestamp,ISNULL(LEAD(A.Timestamp,1)OVER(PARTITION BY A.VisitorSessionId ORDER BY A.Timestamp),A.Timestamp)),0) AS SessionSeconds,
                        A.LogedUserID
        
                FROM    Portal_Logger A(NOLOCK)
                JOIN    D_MASTER B(NOLOCK) ON A.LogedUserID=B.User_Id
                WHERE   A.VisitorSessionId IS NOT NULL
                AND     CAST(A.Timestamp AS DATE) BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate

            )A
            GROUP BY A.AreaAccessed
            ORDER BY NoofTimeAccessed DESC      
        SET NOCOUNT OFF
END
```

Comment: I wish I may make use of your code, but It's does not work. the [AuthenticationFilter(Order = 1)] cast an Exthention, please update your answer.

Comment: Ok, But why `var visitCount = Convert.ToInt64(filterContext.HttpContext.Session["LoggerActivityTracking"].ToString());` from the LoggerActionFilter return Null and therefore braks the process, I think something is missing. don't you have the full implemented code somewhere as a reference? Please, I like your code, and I would like to use in a exercise of mine.

Comment: What is `AuthenticationFilter` ? custom auth filter ? code?

Comment: @Kiquenet  That's another auth filter i had. I removed it from my code as it is not required in this solution

Answer (score 0):

The values would have to be set at some point, either by the user or by code.  You can however, use the `Session` array to contain these values.  They will be preserved for the duration of the login session.

To store to session

```
Session["key"] = "data";
```

and later in code

```
var val = Session["key"]; // val now has a value of "data";
```

Comment: I think using sessions in mvc is bad idea

Comment: @Polaris That is news to me - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744493/still-ok-to-use-session-variables-in-asp-net-mvc-or-is-there-a-better-alternati - Any particular reason why you think they are a bad option?

Comment: @Polaris Why bad idea ?

Answer (score 0):

what I use is a  helper method that use reflection and dumps the model into a dictionary, that way you don't have the issue to copy the values elsewhere, everything ships from a single place "your model"

```
private static Dictionary<string, string> DumpModel(object obt)
        {
            Type type = obt.GetType();
            if (TypeDefinitionIsList(type))
                return null;

            PropertyInfo[] properties = obt.GetType().GetProperties();
            Func<PropertyInfo, string> func = info =>
                                                  {
                                                      if (info.PropertyType.GetInterface(typeof (ICatalogue<>).FullName) != null)
                                                      {
                                                          dynamic propertyValue = info.GetValue(obt, null);
                                                          if (propertyValue != null)
                                                              return string.Format("{{ Id: {0}, Description: {1} }}",
                                                                                   propertyValue.Id,
                                                                                   propertyValue.Description);
                                                          return "null";
                                                      }
                                                      object normalValue = info.GetValue(obt, null);
                                                      if (normalValue == null) return "null";
                                                      return TypeDefinitionIsList(normalValue.GetType()) ? HelpersMessages.NotSupportedList : normalValue.ToString();
                                                  };

            return properties.ToDictionary(x => "model-"+x.Name, func);
        }
```

you can use it in your filter attribute

```
var request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
object model = filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model;
```

and you can use something like

```
 DumpModel(model);
```

use the values to log wharever you need,
I hope this helps